# Using UIBeizerPath on Circle

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, geometry

I want to make a circle which can be cut by percent, for example, 0.25 is 1/4 of the circle.

This is my code so far:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 100,y: 300), radius: CGFloat(20), startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI + M_PI_2), endAngle:CGFloat(90 * M_PI / 180, clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath

        //change the fill color
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        //you can change the stroke color
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        //you can change the line width
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

In startAngle I wrote `CGFloat(M_PI + M_PI_2)` because the start of the circle doesnt start in 0 but as in this picture:

[image]

In the `endAngle` line I wrote `CGFloat(90 * M_PI / 180)` because the formula from degrees to radians is: **degrees*pi/180** .

BUT! In the view I get half of the circle and not quarter of the circle:

[image]

Does my endAngle formula is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in iOS the top of the circle starts at 270 degrees, the startAngle is:

```
startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI + M_PI_2)
```

And the endAngle is:

```
endAngle:CGFloat((360 * 0.25 - 90)
```

Instead of 0.25, you can change it to any number between 0 to 1 (for example: if you want half of the circle to be full, change it to 0.5)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is for your start angle to be 0 and your end angle to be 90 * PI/180

What you have now is a curve that starts at the bottom 270, aka M_PI + M_PI/2 and goes to 90 (90 * M_PI / 180)

//Possibly what you want is for your endAngle = (90 * M_PI/180) + startAngle , aka a quarter more than where you started, i'm not sure which quarter of the circle you want

Comment: True that 270 degrees is the bottom of the circle in a standard coordinate system, but in the UIKit coordinate system it's the top – and 90 degrees is the bottom (as the y-axis is flipped).

Comment: Oh gotcha.  Darn why don't they keep it standard.

Comment: @originaluser2 Thank you for noticing, I figured out the formula:
`startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI + M_PI_2), endAngle:CGFloat((360 * 0.25 - 90)` . when you can change 0.25 to any number between 0 to 1